# Query terminate with semicolon(;) get SqlException and process does not terminate

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

Say my query is

```
select * from table_a where pk=1;
```

If run this query(with semicolon) from Java using PreparedStatement, then a `SqlExpection` is thrown.
I am using Oracle 10g and java 5.

My question is :Though query is valid one, why SqlException(ORA-00911: invalid character) occurred when query is executed form java prepared statement ?

Comment: which database are u using?

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: You don't need to terminate the prepared statement. Does it work if you omit the semicolon? Also what is the exception. I'm sure it doesn't say just "SqlException"

Comment: My question is:Though query is valid one why SqlException  occurred when query is executed form java prepared statement  ?

Comment: Remove the `;` from your Java String as suggested by both answers

Comment: This question is almost 9 years old, but this problem is still around. And removing the semicolon is not a solution. What if you are reading sql from a file with multiple statements, for example? Oracle never fails to surprise with its limitations

Answer (score 4):

Statement terminators are not part of the statement itself. The JDBC API is intended to execute individual statements, so a statement should not be terminated.

For most databases, the statement terminator is not part of the statement syntax, but is actually an artifact of the CLI (which needs to know when a query is actually finished to be sent to the server).

Answer (score 0):

This behavior depends on the database driver you are using. Java PreparedStatement will send this query terminated with semi-colon(;), as it is, to the driver.It depends on the database whether that understands the sql query termination or not.