# ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended exception

Tags: oracle, jdbc

```
SELECT * FROM SMFTABLE WHERE (Upper(SYMBOL) LIKE '%A%' );
```

The above query is giving an

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended exception

the query is built by the following code:

```
buff.append("SELECT * FROM ").append(smftable).append(" WHERE (Upper(" + (String) colNames).append(") LIKE '%").append(secString.toUpperCase()).append("%' );");
```

Comment: What is the value of `smftable`, and where is this (string?) variable being defined?

Comment: What is the content of `secString` did you check if it contains any single quotes?

Comment: smftable contains "SMFTABLE" as its value and secString contains the string to search as in the given query 'A' or 'a'

Answer (score 0):

Remove `;` from the end as JDBC does not require it. Try this once..

Comment: Trailing semicolon should not break the query (I think).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: yes it will, but with a different error message: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10728377

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I seem to recall using semicolon with JDBC and MySQL.  From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18941539/is-the-semicolon-necessary-in-sql) I learned that some drivers remove it, and others will fail with error.  It is not necessary in all cases (I think).

Comment: Yeah. I did try removing it but it didnt change the outcome i.e about the exception